# How to convert IFC file to OBJ File...?

Tags: ifc, xbim

I am trying to convert IFC file to OBJ and Reverse OBJ to IFC using C# .Net.
If any body has any idea. Help me to achieve this functionality.

Comment: check out the following repository to convert IFC To Gltf or Glb: https://github.com/GanguLabs/ifc2gltf-csharp. This might give you some ideas

Answer (score 0):

For Ifc-to-Obj, you should take a look at the Xbim framework (xbimteam on github) as you will be able to generate triangulated polyhedron and then turn it into OBJ data.

In all cases, without a framework for parsing your Ifc file, you won't be able to go anywhere ...

It is going to be hard in opposite Obj-to-Ifc direction, as OBJ format does not contains building element informations you'll need to create an Ifc.

Answer (score 0):

Might come a bit late, and I know that it doesn't directly answer the question regarding the programming language, but if you have the possibility to use JavaScript/NodeJS, you could use the [ifc-convert package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ifc-convert) based also on IfcOpenShell. It worked fine for me. Hope it helps.